# How does vim help files allow visual word selection to select text with periods?

Tags: vim

I've noticed that when I use the commands `viw` in vim help files, it is able to select strings like: `intro.txt`

But when I create a basic file and add the text `intro.txt` and try to select the entire string using `viw` the visual selection stops at the `.`, so I am only able to select `intro` without the `.txt` portion.

Can someone explain why this is, and how I can force vim to select the entire string?

Comment: `viW` selects the whole Word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the built-in help:

```
:help iw
```

```
iw          "inner word", select [count] words (see |word|).
```

... `word`:

```
A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
tabs, <EOL>).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
is also considered to be a word.
```

... `'iskeyword'`:

```
'iskeyword' 'isk'   string (Vim default for MS-DOS and Win32:
                        "@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"
                   otherwise:  "@,48-57,_,192-255"
                Vi default: "@,48-57,_")
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
Keywords are used in searching and recognizing with many commands:
"w", "*", "[i", etc.  It is also used for "\k" in a |pattern|.  See
'isfname' for a description of the format of this option.  For C
programs you could use "a-z,A-Z,48-57,_,.,-,>".
For a help file it is set to all non-blank printable characters except
'*', '"' and '|' (so that CTRL-] on a command finds the help for that
command).
```